# Get Response Headers From WebClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, webclient

I'm trying to upload a file using WebClient, but I can't seem to find a way to get the response headers once the file is uploaded I'm using [this Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.responseheaders?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Net_WebClient_ResponseHeaders) to get the headers, but it just returns null. My code looks like this:

```
public void UploadPart(string filePath, string preSignedUrl)
{
   WebClient wc = new();
   wc.UploadProgressChanged += WebClientUploadProgressChanged;
   wc.UploadFileCompleted += WebClientUploadCompleted;
   wc.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(preSignedUrl), "PUT", filePath);

   // Obtain the WebHeaderCollection instance containing the header name/value pair from the response.
   WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = wc.ResponseHeaders;

   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myWebHeaderCollection);
}
```

I can confirm that the headers exist because I'm able to get them using an HttpWebResponse upload implementation in another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method should be written like this.

```
public Task UploadPart(string filePath, string preSignedUrl)
{
   WebClient wc = new();
   wc.UploadProgressChanged += WebClientUploadProgressChanged;
   wc.UploadFileCompleted += WebClientUploadCompleted;
   await wc.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(preSignedUrl), "PUT", filePath);

   // Obtain the WebHeaderCollection instance containing the header name/value pair from the response.
   WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = wc.ResponseHeaders;

   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myWebHeaderCollection);
}
```

Replace void with Task.
Use await in UploadFileAsyn because it may possible without request complete code jump to next line.

Comment: I just tried this, and it seems I need to add the async keyword to UploadPart or the method shows an error that await can only be used in an async member. When I do however, await wc.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(preSignedUrl), "PUT", filePath); displays the error: "Cannot await void"

Comment: Looks like I needed to use UploadFileTaskAsync in place of UploadFileAsync. In doing so, your code above works great. Could you edit your answer to use UploadFileTaskAsync and I'll mark it as correct?